# Performing Distributed Operations over the Network Without Duplication

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, rest, network-programming

I need to write some code that polls a REST webservice, does some processing on the results, and then transmits the result of that processing on to yet another REST service.  No big deal.

However, the processing can take some time.  For performance's sake, I want to be able to run my program on several machines, such that they each take some of the data from the webservice for processing, so as to distribute the load across multiple machines.  I would like for this to happen in a non-centralized way; that is, I would like to be able to spin up new instances when the load is heavy and shut them down when it is not without having to reconfigure any of the instances.  As a side benefit, this sort of architecture would give me a certain degree of built-in redundancy; if one of the instances fails or goes down, the others should automatically pick up the slack.

What sorts of libraries/tools/patterns are available to implement this sort of architecture in .NET?

Comment: How many messages per second do you expect? is your data precious?

Comment: Precious in the sense that losing data would be considered unacceptable, but if someone puts a gun to my head then I hope they like their shiny new data.  I don't have firm figures for messages/second yet, which is why I'm trying to design ahead of time for scalability.

Comment: If i were you i would use RabbitMQ which has brokers,but brokers do not necessarily mean centralized , its meant for precious data and does persistance out of the box and its the easist of all to work with, ZeroMQ is meant for performance thats why it  does not have persistance by default and its what you call Decentralized, other options are NSQ, NetMQ(a zeromq port to c#) and nsq which is written in go does persistance when you tell it to and outperforms all of what i mentioned, but if you don't expect 40-70k messages second then RabbitMQ.

Comment: Does someone care to explain the "off topic" vote-to-close?  I'm not sure I understand how a question about "writing code that performs distributed operations on a network" is off topic for this site...

Comment: @decoherence Don't I still have to write some distributed code in .NET to go from the Web Service to the RabbitMQ?

Comment: sure but thats really minimal if you use RabbitMQ they have  couple good examples on clustering and work queues, work queues is what you need, all the features that you wish for RabbitMQ is the only one that has them, i tend to use it the most in production, and NSQ when i just don't care about reliability and advanced features, you can start here https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-dotnet.html , load balancing for free